# how to append different column values and convert it into numeric months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table below.

### Updated Questions (adding one more column called Cust ID

| Cust ID | Jan Transaction Fee | Jan Transaction Fee | Jan Product Fee | Jan Product Fee | Feb Transaction Fee | Feb Transaction Fee | Feb Product Fee | Feb Product Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | HKD | USD | HKD | USD | HKD | USD | HKD | USD |
| 100103 | 100 | 20 | 21 | 24 | 215 | 55 | 253 | 25 |
| 100104 | 200 | 30 | 31 | 34 | 315 | 65 | 353 | 35 |

I would like to convert the table from above to the below expected result.

| Cust ID | Period | Type | FX | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100103 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 100 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | USD | 20 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Product Fee | HKD | 21 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Product Fee | USD | 24 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 215 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | USD | 55 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Product Fee | HKD | 253 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Product Fee | USD | 25 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 200 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | USD | 30 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Product Fee | HKD | 31 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Product Fee | USD | 34 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 315 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | USD | 65 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Product Fee | HKD | 353 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Product Fee | USD | 35 |

My coding on import data is below

```
import pandas as pd 


test=pd.DataFrame({'Cust ID':['','100103','100104'],'Jan Transaction Fee':['HKD',100,200],'Jan Transaction Fee.1':['USD',20,30],\
                  'Jan Product Fee':['HKD',21,31],'Jan Product Fee.1':['USD',24,34],
                  'Feb Transaction Fee':['HKD',215,315],'Feb Transaction Fee.1':['USD',55,65],
                  'Feb Product Fee':['HKD',253,353],'Feb Product Fee.1':['USD',25,35]})

test
```

I am just a beginner in Python. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: How is created DataFrame? By `pd.read_csv(file, header=False)` ?

Comment: Yes,i used read_excel to import data. I just used pd.DataFrame here just for someone wanna loading my script, as it seems Stack overflow can't attach excel file here

Comment: Are data confidental? If not, is possible share your file, eg. with 3 rows, 5 columns?

Comment: i can share the data, how can i attach the file here?

Comment: try solution bellow, if not working let me know.

Comment: Yes, the solution below works for me. BTW, do you know why the above concat function remove my previous value instead of append new value into the bottom under test column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could set labels, [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), and [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the Type column into Type and period (with reworking the date):

```
df = test.set_axis(['Type', 'FX', 'Price']).T
# or renaming by numerical index
# df = test.rename({0: 'Type', 1: 'FW', 2: 'Price'}).T

df[['Period', 'Type']] = df['Type'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)

df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime('2022 '+df['Period']).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

output:

```
              Type   FW Price  Period
0  Transaction Fee  HKD   100  202201
1  Transaction Fee  USD    20  202201
2      Product Fee  HKD    21  202201
3      Product Fee  USD    24  202201
4  Transaction Fee  HKD   215  202202
5  Transaction Fee  USD    55  202202
6      Product Fee  HKD   253  202202
7      Product Fee  USD    25  202202
```

###### Period as YYYYMMDD integer with DD as MonthEnd

```
df['Period'] = (pd.to_datetime('2022 '+df['Period'])
                  .add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd())
                  .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                  .astype(int)
               )
```

Comment: Yes, i just tried. It works. Thank so much. But i have two follow up questions. 
1. If i wanna show Period "20220131" and "20220228", how can i do it?  Even i change the strftime('%Y%m%d'), it just show the start date instead of ending date

2. The period format is now character. How can i show it as numeric if i show the period format as "YYYYMMDD" ?

Comment: @TonyTang check the update ;)

Comment: I have just added one column which is called Cust ID on the table. If the table is like that, is it still possible to have the expected table?

Comment: Hi @mozway , not sure if you see my last comment there.  I have spent hours on the additional cust id there, but still no any progress.  Hope you dont mind to help me again.  Thanks

Comment: @Tony it would be possible but it becomes tricky. At this point better try to import correctly the data ;)

Comment: thanks for your kind reply.  I have already edited the question part.  You can directly use my import code for your reference. Btw,  python doesnt allow me to use the same name for columm name,  so i have added '. 1' behind the column name for all the usd column so that i can see all columns in python